# [iPhone]:Detecting you tube player controls using javaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview, embed

I am using an embed tag to play youtube video in my iPhone application.
It works fine. But I need to detect the controls in it such as pause,play and end.
I have tried the following event handling methods which doesnt seem to work.
onPause, onPlay etc.

Here is my html code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11      /DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
    function capturePause() 
    {
        alert('capturePause Event Called');
    }
    function captureEnd() 
    {
        alert('captureEnd Event Called');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body style="margin-left:0px">
<embed id="youtube" src="http://youtube url" width="450" height="450" autostart="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" EnableJavaScript="true" onPause="capturePause();" wmode="transparent" >
</body>
```

Note that i had used onPause event. But the script is not getting called if I pause the video. Even the auto start atrribute is not working.

Is there any way that I can detect the controls using java script in my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should try using the built in you tube application in iPhone... open that and it will provide all the functionality you need.

if you wanto use the embed tags...try installing flash player newest version on iphone and use that instead...

Comment: If we use the built in youtube app, then i guess  it would quit my current app and launch the you tube app. But as per my requirements I need to ve the video played in witchin my app.

Answer (score 0):

not really...u dont have to quit...infact it would just open in full screen and when the video closes, make an IBAction method which will fire to relaunch your app (keep in mind that the applicationdidenterforeground in appdelegate will need to be updated and also applicationdidbecomeactive...